# PHP 5.3 accessing array key from object getter

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a Form object $form. One of its variables is a Field object which represents all fields and is an array (e.g `$this->field['fieldname']`). The getter is `$form->fields()`.

To access a specific field method (to make it required or not for example) I use `$form->fields()['fieldname']` which works on localhost with wamp but on the server throws this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in (...)
```

I have PHP 5.3 on the server and because I reinstalled wamp and forgot to change it back to 5.3, wamp runs PHP 5.4. So I guess this is the reason for the error.

How can I access an object method, which returns an array, by the array key with PHP 5.3?

Comment: Use a temporary variable: `$fields = $form->fields; echo $fields['fieldname'];`

Comment: Just to explain what's going on here, this behaviour introduced in PHP 5.4 is called function array dereferencing. Documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [5.4 dereferencing to valid 5.3 array call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711654/5-4-dereferencing-to-valid-5-3-array-call)

Comment: more details in the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

Comment: Cheers - I didn't know its name so couldn't find the other posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array dereferencing as described in the question is a feature that was only added in PHP 5.4. PHP 5.3 cannot do this.

```
echo $form->fields()['fieldname']
```

So this code will work in PHP 5.4 and higher.

In order to make this work in PHP 5.3, you need to do one of the following:

1. Use a temporary variable:

   ```
   $temp = $form->fields()
   echo $temp['fieldname'];
   ```
2. Output the fields array as an object property rather than from a method:
   ie this....

   ```
   echo $form->fields['fieldname']
   ```

   ...is perfectly valid.
3. Or, of course, you could upgrade your server to PHP 5.4. Bear in mind that 5.3 will be declared end-of-life relatively soon, now that 5.5 has been released, so you'll be wanting to upgrade sooner or later anyway; maybe this is your cue to do? (and don't worry about it; the upgrade path from 5.3 to 5.4 is pretty easy; there's nothing really that will break, except things that were deprecated anyway)

Comment: Cheers! I need to convince my host to give me 5.4, they only offer it for new accounts which is slightly ridiculous...

Answer (score 3):

Array dereferencing is possible as of PHP 5.4, not 5.3

PHP.net:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately that means I cannot modify my $form object (since the $form->fields() has a lot of setters) because using temporary variables would only be useful for display.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned array dereferencing is only possible in 5.4 or greater.
But you can save the object and later on access the fields:

```
$fields=$form->fields();
$value=$fields['fieldname']
...
```

AFAIK there is no other option.